# my traverse method wont pass down the value of int but can pass down the value of ArrayList

Tags: java, int, immutability, traversal

My god feeling tells me the answer is "Integer and String are immutable", but I want to get confirmation from experts here.

I have a traverse method, which basically will traverse the whole tree starting from the root. Here are two types of usage, first one wont work, always return 0, second one works, the result ArrayList can accumulate in traverse.

Here is the first one:

```
public int whateverSum(TreeNodeType root, int target) {
    int sum = 0;
    traverse(root, target, sum);
    return sum;
}
```

Here is the second one:

```
public List<String> whateverSum(TreeNode root, int target) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    traverse(root, target, result);
    return result;
}
```

Please help me the confirm my thought if it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it right. In fact, what happens is that the traverse method passes down the value of an int but not the value of the ArrayList.

Well, what happens is the difference between values and reference. When you are passing down an int to a function, the value is copied. The function accesses the copy of the value. It uses it in whichever way possible, but in the end all of the operations are done to the copy of the value, without the original being modified.

When you are passing an Object to a function, you are passing a reference to it, just like a memory address. It makes sense because when you are passing an ArrayList of millions of items, you would rather not want those millions of items being copied everytime. So, what is being copied is the reference to this Object, which point to the original structure.

That's why, when you pass an int to a function, the original value will never be modified. Whereas when you pass an ArrayList, its content will change.

Now, not all objects behave this way, this is where immutable objects come. You said it String are immutables, which is very handy. So, when you do a modification on a String, it is copied and the original value doesn't change either. Types like Integer or Double are also immutable. It makes lots of sense, because when you're incrementing an integers, you don't want all of the 1 of your program becoming 2's.

Regarding your code, in order to get the first method work, you can do something like:

```
public int whateverSum(TreeNodeType root, int target) {
    int sum = traverse(root, target, 0);
    return sum;
}
```

Where traverse returns the updated sum.